# Changing Styling on Individual Leaflet Layer Control Items

Tags: leaflet, javascript, css

How would I go about changing the styling for Individual entries in Leaflets layer control?

For example I would like to change the colour of "Layer 1" to red and the colour of "Layer 2" to blue.

Would this be done through the Javascript or the CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
L.control.layers({}, {
  "<span style='color:red'>Layer 1</span>": layer1,
  "<span style='color:blue'>Layer 2</span>": layer2,
  // etc
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: How would I do it in react-leaflet?  <LayersControl.Overlay name="TEST" checked={true} ></LayersControl.Overlay>.  For instance, make the font bold and red?